# how to test user is or not close the cookie using django

Tags: django, cookies

i use this code :

```
request.session.set_test_cookie()
```

the all code is :

```
def main(request, template_name='index.html'):
    context ={
              'a':a,
              'cookie':request.session.set_test_cookie(),
    }
    return render_to_response(template_name, context)
```

but it return None ,

what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set_test_cookie()` just sets a cookie on the client's browser, it doesn't return anything, hence the `None`

You can't tell if the browser is actually storing that cookie until the next request where you would check if the cookie was successfully set via `test_cookie_worked()` -- that's the test: if the browser doesn't show the cookie you set, it's not accepting cookies. If it does return the cookie, it's proof that cookie are being set, and you'd delete it with `delete_test_cookie()`

Read docs for more info:   I'd be copy and pasting the docs at this point :) 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#setting-test-cookies

Or feel free to ask any questions.